# Minfiying CSS breaks embedded EL expressions

Tags: java, css, jsf-2, el, yui-compressor

We use `yuicompressor-maven-plugin` to compress our css/js resources. Unfortunately, it breaks our embedded EL expressions.

```
body {
    font-size: #{fooBean.fontSize}px;
}
```

becomes

```
body{font-size:#{fooBean.fontSize;}    // note the additional ;
px}
```

which makes the expression unparseable (`Cannot evaluate EL expression fooBean.fontSize; in resource css/foo:style.css`).

Is there any way around? Excluding single css files is no option because most of them are affected. Same for not compressing at all.

Comment: have you tried the [`nomunge`](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/compress-mojo.html) option?

Answer (score 1):

An ***alternative*** (IMO better one) solution would be not to use EL expression in your css.

IMO you better use other css to override that `font-size` , if you want to make some custom specific styling you should create a css per customer in which all those specific rules will override the general one... I don't think that coupling your css to your bean is a good idea.

general-style.css:

```
body {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

custom-xyz-style.css:

```
body {
    font-size: 14px;
```

Just make sure that the *custom-xyz-style.css* will be included after the *general-style.css* file